# Android Show AlertDialog irrespective of the User Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, display

I have three to four Activities

In the fourth activity, I am sending data to Server and finishing the activity and user can be in any of the first three acts.

Irrespective of the which activity user is in, I shud display a Custom AlertDialog to the user asking what to do with the info fetched from the Server.

Try 1 :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogVar = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogVar.create().show();
```

Try 2 :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogVar = new AlertDialog.Builder(namActivity1.this);
alertDialogVar.create().show();
```

Try 3 :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogVar = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
alertDialogVar.create().show();
```

Try 4:

Based the suggestion from below link I even tried broadcasting, but same error

[Displaying a AlertDialog on screen irrespective of Activity Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003140/displaying-a-alertdialog-on-screen-irrespective-of-activity-screen)

I am getting an error Saying the activity is closed while trying to show:

> Error : E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: dijisuji.PicPac, PID: 24381
>                     android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@3c152e1 is not valid; is your activity running?
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:580)
>                         at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
>                         at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>                         at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)

How do I make this appear irrespective of the active user is in?

Comment: one simple solution to your problem is don't finish your fourth activity as you send the request from server. Instead show the dialog box and on dialog box button click finish your fourth activity and go to whatever activity you like

Comment: No i dont want to make user wait seeing the progress. They can keep seeing things in other activity

Comment: ok then do one thing you hit the request from an Intent service and once the request is complete show the dialog from that service.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple approach would be to make a BaseActivity which all your other activities would extend, in that case, you can simply use the context of BaseActivity without worrying about on which activity user is, as it will always contain the instance of current activity.

```
class Act1 extends BaseActivity{}

class Act2 extends BaseActivity{}

class Act3 extends BaseActivity{}

class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
      public void showDialog(){
         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogVar = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
         alertDialogVar.create().show();
      }
}
```

now any activity can call this BaseActivity's showDialog() method.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you change the activity notify your server communicating class in which activity you are with a static method. And simply use the last activity notified to show your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to incorporate interfaces. You can implement your interface in all of your activities and display the dedicated error message you need. Does not matter where the trigger is from, with the current context, the method will be called and you can display your error dialog.

I had a similar situation where I had to call error dialog on return of a background API call, I incorporated interface and override the method in all of my activities, does not matter which screen I'm on, if the API fails, I call my interface method and my error dialog is shown.